# How can I remotely tell what brand/model internal SCSI card is installed in a machine?

Tags: windows-server-2003, hardware, scsi

I am doing some consulting work for a previous employer upgrading and migrating old servers to new hardware.

There is an existing file server (HP ProLiant DL380) that has an tape backup drive connected; it is using a SCSI interface and I'm pretty sure it's using an internal SCSI card.

They are upgrading to a new server hardware (HP ProLiant DL160 G6).  The old server is 2U, the new one 1U and we would want to move the tape drive to the new server, too.  I'm trying to figure out if the SCSI card in the old server would be able to be installed in the new one or if we'll need to source a new card; mostly I don't know for sure the height of the card and if it's low-profile enough that it would fit in the new server.

There is not much of a technical resource onsite and the old server is in-use anyway so I would like to avoid making a trip in myself or trying to have someone onsite pop open the case and tell me what card is there.

It's running Windows Server 2003 - is there a way to tell from say Device Manager what make and model the SCSI card might be?  Or any other system diagnostic program or something that would give me hardware info like that?

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 2):

In Device Manager under SCSI and RAID controllers you should see the SCSI card and should be able to get the info you need.

Comment: That will tell you the driver being used. It might not map to the exact model nomenclature used by HP, however.

Comment: I tend to spend time googling the DeviceID which is specific to a model, and just hoping that I see the same thing in someone elses pastebin that helps me identify it

Answer (score 1):

This can be viewed remotely via **wmic**.

***Command Prompt*** > ***WMIC /NODE:hostname DISKDRIVE >C:\diskdrive.txt***

Output will provide you with a variety of parameters among which are

- Device ID (SCSI\DISK&VEN_ADAPTEC&PROD_ARRAY&REV_V1.0\5&1AD12BA&0&040000);
- Model (IBM ServeRAID M1015 SCSI Disk Device);
- Firmware ver.;
- etc.

Here is an example of info gathered from IBM server (txt file output has more human-readable format).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would help a lot!  It looks like the DISKDRIVE option dumps info about hte physical disk drive management.  Would this include internal SCSI cards and external tape drives, though?  Or is there a more appropriate command? I see there's a "SCSICONTROLLER" command, too.

Comment: Seems like for external tapes this switch "TAPEDRIVE" should be used.
[More commands](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

Answer (score 0):

Both 1 and 2U servers should have a riser card with the PCI cards being installed sideways.  The same cards should fit in both servers.